# JavaScript quiz redirect issue

Tags: javascript, redirect

I'm trying to code a quiz which will redirect to one of two secondary quizzes depending on the answers chosen. I have the below code which I thought would work but instead it either completes the else return or reloads the quiz. The secondary quiz is located within ques2.html and the third within ques3.html. Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong, or have any potential solutions?

```
var data = {
    questions: [{
            question: "Which interests you most?",
            options: [ "Medicine" , "Physics" ]
        }, {
            question: "Which interests you most?",
            options: [ "Vet/Animals" , "Astrology"]
        }, {
            question: "Which interests you most?",
            options: [ "Nutrition" , "Chemistry"]
        }, {
            question: "Which interests you most?",
            options: [ "Psychology" , "Forensic Science" ]
        }, {
            question: "Which interests you most",
            options: [ "Dentistry" , "Biology"]

        }],

};

var qIndex = 0,
    index = 0,
    aString = "",
    maxQ = 5,
    q = document.getElementById('ques'),
    opt1 = document.getElementById('opt1'),
    opt2 = document.getElementById('opt2');

function generate(){
    q.innerHTML= data.questions[qIndex].question;
    opt1.value= data.questions[qIndex].options[0];
    opt2.value= data.questions[qIndex].options[1];
}

function optionClick(ans) {
    if(qIndex%1==0){
        aString+=ans;
        index++;
    }
    qIndex++;
    if(qIndex == maxQ){

        redirect( generateResult );
    } else{
        generate();
    }
}

function generateResult(answers) {
    if( answers =="00000" || answers =="00001" || answers=="00010" || answers=="00100" || answers=="01000" || answers=="10000" || answers=="00011" || answers=="00110" || answers=="01100" || answers=="11000" || answers=="00101" || answers=="01010" || answers=="10100" || answers=="01001" || answers=="10010" || answers=="10001" ) return "ques2.html";
    else if( answers=="11111" || answers=="11110" || answers=="11101" || answers=="11011" || answers=="10111" || answers=="01111" || answers=="11100" || answers=="11001" || answers=="10011" || answers=="00111" || answers=="11010" || answers=="10101" || answers=="01011" || answers=="10110" || answers=="01101" || answers=="01110" ) return "ques3.html";
    else return "new.html"; 
}


function redirect(url) {
    window.location = url;
}
```

Comment: Where (and how) is your "click handler" optionClick(ans) invoked ?
Have you tried redirect(generateResult(aString)) ?
Make a console.log(aString) inside optionClick ...

Answer (score 1):

When you call your redirect function you have to pass it generateResult with a propertie like this:

```
 redirect( generateResult(anwsers) );
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean to do with this, can you provide me an example, please?

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted in your question, you do

```
redirect( generateResult );
```

... but here, `generateResult` is a reference to the function, it is not *calling* the function, so you are passing a javascript function to `redirect(...)`, you are **not** passing a URL.

To call the function you need the parentheses

```
redirect( generateResult() );
```

-- but then, generateResult is expecting a parameter `answers` as we see in its declaration — so, you need to pass the string you have been building up, `aString`, in your `optionClick(ans)` function

```
redirect( generateResult(aString) );
```

Also, I'm not sure what you're trying to do with this test in optionClick...

```
function optionClick(ans) {
if(qIndex%1==0){
    aString+=ans;
    index++;
}
```

... but anything `N % 1` always leaves a remainder of zero, so `qIndex%1==0` is always true and those two lines are always executed.
Clearly `qIndex` is used, but it looks like `index` is not, and could be removed.

In any case, I've created [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/m6nkLkLd/) where I've stubbed out the functions that interact with the page (since you don't show any html) and just writes to the browser console. It simulates having clicked on options in order: 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 and correctly outputs that it would go to page `ques2.html`.

An [update to the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/m6nkLkLd/1/) strips out the parts that are unnecessary, based on what I've written above, and shows a different sequence: 0,1,1,0,1 which outputs `ques3.html`.

Comment: I did originally have that within it and then changed it to see if anything changed. I still have the same problem. It either loads the else return and reloads the new.html or reloads the page